# Getting OnPageChangeListener to change Text View

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a FragmentAdapter in a View Pager and it's all functioning correctly. Except, I need to a set an OnPageChangeListener so I can notify a TextView when the page has changed.

So this is what I have:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        tView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        ...
    }

    ...


    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        tView1.setText("You are at position " + position);

    }


    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        tView1.setText("You are at position " + position);

    }
```

Except the 2 override "page" methods above don't even run when I swipe through pages. I have tried adding a print statement too, but nothing happens?

Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you setting the listener anywhere? setOnPageChangeListener(...)

Comment: I just implemented the methods?

Comment: That is not enough.... Do you know how listeners work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add to your `OnCreate`

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

that's what's missing. You didn't pass the listener to the pager.

Comment: This causes my program to crash, there must be something else I'm doing wrong